# how does CDN routing work

Tags: domain-name-system, cdn

So, I know how a CDN works in principle and how it works from a customer's perspective. My question is more about the root of how they work, the routing. My limited knowledge points to just some fancy DNS work. Something along the lines of [Geoipdns](http://pub.mud.ro/wiki/Geoipdns). Is that about right?

So, if I wanted to create my own little CDN, the practicality of which is beyond this question, and I had servers on west coast, central and east, then all I would need is my own DNS servers that looked at the incoming ip, mapped its location and routed accordingly, yes?

Comment: They work by misusing the DNS system :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

I doubt serverfault is gonna let me hit submit on a 4 character post though... so ahhh... also they'll usually bgp-anycast the ip's of the dns servers so that it can both be fault tolerant and have a good default-guess at which location you're going to be closer to.

Answer (score 0):

Basically yes - although some smart ones are placed in specific locations to optimise delivery - ours are anyway.